# How to increase number of displayed rows in Oracle Reports 6i?

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

I have a tabular report in Oracle Reports 6i, and when I print it, it produces a large margin at the bottom and continues to print the remaining rows/records on the next page. The orientation of the printout is *portrait*. I increased the number of maximum records per page, but when it prints it won't go beyond the number of rows it's been printing, and it's like the change is of no effect.

Answer (score 0):

When in Paper Layout editor, check the **margin** layout. Thick black line shows "usable" part of the report - check whether it is stretched through the whole paper size.

Also, see whether paper size is correctly set. For example, for portrait A4 paper, it should be 21 cm wide and 29.7 cm high.

Furthermore, data is contained within a **frame**; actually, two of them (repeating and ... well, the one that encloses it; its default name begins with an `M`). See their **vertical elasticity** properties. Should be either **variable** or **expand** (maybe one (or both) of them are now *fixed*).